# Run Angular App in .Net Core in directory other than wwwroot

Tags: angular, asp.net-core

As the post title suggests, I'm attempting to build a .Net Core web application that also hosts an Angular application. The .Net Core web app serves as a wrapper to the Angular app in order to secure all of the resources of the Angular app (images, scripts, etc) so that they are only accessible once a user has authenticated.

I've read a host of posts about deploying an Angular app within a .Net Core site, but it seems invariably they all seem to be predicated on the Angular files being dropped into the wwwroot. However, doing so does not fulfill my requirement to lock all of the resources down until after authentication. The user workflow should be that when they hit the site, they are redirected to a login page, and upon successful authentication, they are then sent to a controller method that is the entry point for the Angular application.

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44975048/net-core-serving-html-file-outside-wwwroot-cant-load-js-files), which seems to be right in line with what I need, but did not have a successful answer, so thought I'd post the question myself.

I did also find in my research, looking at the documentation for [Static Files in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x), it states the following regarding Static Files:

> The static file middleware doesn't provide authorization checks. Any >files served by it, including those under wwwroot, are publicly >accessible. To serve files based on authorization:
>
> 1. Store them outside of wwwroot and any directory accessible to the static file middleware and
> 2. Serve them via an action method to which authorization is applied. Return a FileResult object

After reading this, and pondering it, and playing around with it, I suddenly came to a question in my own mind: Given the difficulty posed in the other question by David referenced above, does this mean that if you want to lock down a static file and require authentication, the only way to serve the file is via a controller action that returns the FileResult, meaning that any script file or image file asset for the Angular application would have to accessed via this controller method? Presumably, then, you'd have to reference those files via a url that would cause a controller method to return the file.

If that is the case, given the way the Angular CLI chunks up the scripts, it would seem this would be an untenable solution. Am I understanding that correctly? Is there a more appropriate way to lock down all of the angular related resources until a user has authenticated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I appreciate the efforts to answer. Ultimately, I was able to get where I needed, partly based on the answer to [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36775942/how-do-i-serve-static-files-only-to-authorized-users)

To solve the problem, I created a folder in the site to hold my angular application. Using the info from the other question regarding the creation of a custom middleware, I was able to create the middleware to use for protecting my static angular folder content. I added this middleware in my startup.cs referencing the path for my angular files, and then added an app.UseStaticFiles entry that provided the access to the angular directory i created.

By placing the middleware prior to the StaticFiles middleware for that directory, it is able to evaluate user policy authentication prior to serving the static files.

That did ultimately wreak havoc with a lot of path structures in the angular application, but I was able to work through them all to set the appropriate build properties, etc, such that now I can build the angular application, drop it in my static folder for the client app, and it's all protected by the .net authentication.

Answer (score 0):

As you've said, one solution is to bundle the Angular artifact into the .NET Core wwwroot/ and that limits you.

I think you're halfway there in thinking of a better solution, but I don't think forcing kestrel to serve static files outside of wwwroot/ is the solution.

When packaging Angular inside of .NET Core's wwwroot/ you are basically leveraging the already running kestrel as the web server to host your Angular app, and the only thing that kestrel needs to do is serve static files. And the only dependency of Angular on your .NET Core App is the API endpoints.

That being said, I think the optimal solution would be to simply not try to rely upon kestrel as a host for your Angular app.

Although there are many options, I would use Nginx or IIS, which will act as a reverse proxy so it can serve each of your apps.

I am currently working on a project which has a .NET Core API, an Angular App, and a Mongo DB instance all running on Docker. It works quite well and I know this is a viable solution.

### Update

Based on your latest comment, I realized what your asking for is not a coded solution, but a IIS configuration / permissions solution.

Like you said, Kestrel doesn't provide authorization for serving static files, and you don't want to serve each file through a controller. You've obviously read and understand the "Static Files" section on the ASP.NET Core Docs so we need something else.

Check out [this article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/815151/how-to-restrict-specific-users-from-gaining-access-to-specified-web-re) and let me know if this is of any help or not.

Comment: Up until the fourth paragraph, this was an ok answer. Kestrel is NOT a reverse proxy, in fact, you **need** Nginx (in your example) to serve **as** the reverse proxy. Kestrel is an HTTP server. That said, in case you are interested, Visual Studio 2017.8 (now in Preview) already generates a project for the API and another project for the Angular/React front-end, so they are officially separated

Comment: Great news about the VS preview! I'm going to check it out ASAP.

Comment: In this particular case, the site will be hosted on IIS, but I'm unclear as to how that solves the problem. Let me add a little more detail. In this particular case, the client does not want any of the resources (including the images, js files, etc) publicly accessible until a user is authenticated. So we have to create a .net login page, and only after a user is authenticated, bootstrap the angular site for them to access. As i understand it based on the documentation posted, there is no way to lock down any staticfiles directory, outside of serving them via a controller.

Comment: I actually was looking for a coded solution. I was able to work it out, and have added an answer here, in case you are wondering about it. Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 0):

In my case (**.NET 7**) the Angular app is published to a sub folder inside `dist` folder. (It was because how we have setup the Angular projects/libraries). So the `index.html` was inside `dist/Portal.App/index.html`.
Related segment from the **angular.json**,

```
...
         "options": {
            "progress": false,
            "outputPath": "dist/Portal.App",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",

...
```

Then in the `Program.cs`, I had to add/change `UseDefaultFiles`, `UseStaticFiles`, `MapFallbackToFile` middlewares to serve the static files over **IIS**, by creating an instance of `PhysicalFileProvider`.

**Program.cs**

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

//==========Changed here=================
var fileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
    Path.Combine(app.Environment.WebRootPath, "Portal.App"));
app.UseDefaultFiles(new DefaultFilesOptions
{
    FileProvider = fileProvider,
    RequestPath = "",
    DefaultFileNames = new[] { "index.html" }
});
//==========Changed here=================
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
    FileProvider = fileProvider,
    RequestPath = ""
});

app.UseRouting();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

//==========And here=================
app.MapFallbackToFile("index.html", new StaticFileOptions
{
    FileProvider = fileProvider,
    RequestPath = ""
});

app.Run();
```

That was it. We haven't really changed the `.csproj` file or added a `web.config` to the project. But I'll leave a link to the `.csproj` file [here](https://gist.github.com/nishanc/16f6ba22146dcde8311ea56a6f9cafda#file-portal-app-csproj) just in case.